# I installed SElinux in my Jetson AGX Xavier, ubuntu 22.04. Now my system is stuck at boot

Tags: 22.04, selinux

I have access to UEFI shell. I thought of changing the boot parameters. But when I am using cd command the command is retuning current directory not specified.